# Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open "Filename" when uploading an image to Cyclic.sh

Tags: node.js, storage, multer, cyclic

I am trying to first upload my image "formData" to the backend, then use the image path to upload it to ImageBB.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './tmp')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/tmp'));
app.use('./tmp', express.static('tmp'));

app.post(
//Uploading to ImageBB
);
```

This seems to work fine in my localhost, BUT when I deployed it on Cyclic.sh , this error appears in the logs:
`Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open "Filename"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's solved. 
Though all I did was changing the `./tmp` to `/tmp`.